# Proof weird function is discontinuous/has no partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm asked to analyze the continuity and existence of partial derivatives at the origin, and even though it seems pretty obvious that this function is discontinuous at that point, I can't seem to prove it via the standard limits. Any tips are welcome.

$$ f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill y^2    \hfill & y\in \Bbb Q \\
      \hfill 0 \hfill & y\in \Bbb R -\Bbb Q \\
  \end{cases}
$$

E: Could anyone graph this function with mathematica (or any software) I'd like to know how it looks, but I don't have mathematica at home and don't know how to use other software.

Comment: You don't need mathematica.  Go to www.wolframalpha.com and type in "plot f(x,y) = y^2".

Comment: You just need to fill in what our function here is doing differently than the "f(x,y) = y^2" function.  Ours is also going to $0$ when $y$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall h\neq 0,\quad \left | \frac{f(0,0+h)-f(0,0)}{h} \right |<\left | \frac{h^{2}}{h} \right |=\vert h\vert $ so if we let $h\to 0$, we see that $f_y(0,0)=0$.

Likewise,

$\forall h\neq 0,\quad \left | \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} \right |=\left | \frac{0}{h} \right |=0$ so $f_x(0,0)=0$.

Now, $\vert f(x,y)-f(0,0)\vert <y^{2}$ which is $<\epsilon $ as soon as $(x,y)\in  B_{\sqrt \epsilon }(0,0)$ so $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @user46944 thanks

Comment: Could you explain a bit your answer?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: try doing a similar analysis on the function $f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill y^2    \hfill & y\in \Bbb Q \\
      \hfill 1 \hfill & y\in \Bbb R -\Bbb Q \\
  \end{cases}$ and you'll see how all this works!

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)$ isn't discontinuous at $(0,0)$.  How do I know?

First of all, can you get a picture of this function in your head?  I can.  Since $f: \Bbb R^{2} \to \Bbb R$, you should think of this function as first taking the $XY$-plane in $3$D space (let it be the horizontal axes), and warp that plane.  In this case, we are warping the plane like a taco.  If you are still confused, go to the WolframAlpha website and type "plot f(x,y) = y^2".  Our function looks almost like this, except when $y$ is irrational, we have the output $0$, so it's kind of like two planes -- one is a constant $0$, and the other is the taco, above the constant one.

Now, from the picture, it's clear that any path you take to $0$, the function approaches $0$, too, so the function has to be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Similarly, if you think about the picture, the partial derivative with respect to $x$ exists and is $0$, while the partial derivative with respect to $y$ exists and is $0$, because the limit $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x, 0 + h) - f(x,0)}{h} = 0$.

The only thing you need to worry about while checking this limit is the paths going to $0$. $\lim \limits_{h \to 0, h \in \Bbb Q} \dfrac{f(x, 0 + h) - f(x,0)}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0, h \in \Bbb Q} \dfrac{h^{2} - 0}{h} = 0$,

and

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0, h \not \in \Bbb Q} \dfrac{f(x, 0 + h) - f(x,0)}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0, h \not \in \Bbb Q} \dfrac{0 - 0}{h} = 0$.

Comment: I don't think this function is continuous at any other point than $(0,0)$, though.

Comment: Actually, I think it is continuous at $(x,0)$ for each $x$.

Comment: I thought It would look like a "taco", but with a lot of points cut out, I'm having a lot of trouble picturing it haha. Why does checking those two limits insure the existence of the "full" limit?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD You are right!  It's like a taco, with points cut out everywhere, since both the rationals and irrationals are dense.  I think checking the limit along these two paths is enough, because the limit along any path going to $0$ will be a combination of rationals and irrationals.  If for strictly rational tendency to $0$, the limit is $0$, and for strictly irrational tendency to $0$, the limit is $0$, then I think for any tendency to $0$, the limit will be $0$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't yet studied about dense sets so I couldn't know, to me it *seems* these two limits should guarantee the existence of the general one, but I really don't know for sure.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD The rationals being *dense* in $\Bbb R$ just means between every two real numbers, you can always find a rational number.  Similarly, the irrationals are dense, so between every two real numbers, you can find an irrational number.  Intuitively, this means there are no "pockets" in the real numbers where you can't find rational numbers.  Every pocket (or interval, if you like) contains rationals (and irrationals) -- rationals are everywhere! (So are irrationals).  You can't have an interval that consists of *only* irrational numbers because the rationals are dense (and vice versa)

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I wish I could explain my answer to you in more detail in person, where it would be much easier than via online communication.  I hope you can find someone in person that will adequately be able to explain the answer to your problem.